# Server proxy with Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

I want to build a proxy with node.js to use in my browser.
I searched at google and saw that [example](http://www.catonmat.net/http-proxy-in-nodejs), but some Apis are deprecated.

So I changed the code following:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {

  console.log("req for:"+ request.headers['host'] + "\nmethod: "+  request.method);

  var options = {
    host : request.headers['host'],
    method : request.method,
    headers : request.headers    
  }

  var callback = function(res){
    // get the proxyclient response and write to the original response
    res.addListener('data', function(chunk){
      console.log("writing response");
      response.write(chunk, 'binary');
    });

    res.addListener('end', function(){
      console.log("end response");
      response.end();
    });
  };

  // send the original request
  var proxy = http.request(options, callback);

  // intercept the request and write to proxyclient
  request.addListener('data', function(chunk){
    console.log("new request");
    proxy.write(chunk, 'binary');

  });

  request.addListener('end', function(){
    console.log("end request");
    proxy.end();
  });


}).listen(3333);
```

After that, I changed my browser proxy settings to use localhost:3333. 
My problem is that event "data" isn't fired.

This should work as I thought?

Comment: Are you referring to the event in your callback?

Comment: Both of them, no logs at console for 'data' listeners

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you write this code;

```
 response.writeHead(res.statusCode, res.headers); after res.addListener('end', function(){
  console.log("end response"); 
  response.end();
 });
```